Create a function that converts a dataframe into a format suitable for a treemap structure
I want to create a treemap for a dataframe using the Plotly package. For this purpose, I need to create a function that converts the dataframe into a format suitable for a treemap structure. On the page https://plotly.com/r/treemaps/, there are explanations on how to create a treemap.
I have a dataframe that includes two to multiple grouping variables and one column that specifies the frequency. Therefore, I need to create a function where the input is a dataframe and the name of the frequency column. The output should be structured in a way that is suitable for drawing a treemap. I will use two sample dataframes as test cases for the function, which are presented below:
df_1 <- data.frame(  
  cat_1 = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 2),  
  cat_2 = rep(letters[5:6],  len = 4),  
  
  N = rep(1:2, len = 4)  
) 

df_2<-data.frame(
  cat_1=
    rep(LETTERS[1:4],each=4)
  ,
  cat_2=rep(letters[5:6],each=2,len=16),
  cat_3=rep(LETTERS[7:8],len=16)
  ,
  N=rep(1:4,len=16)
  
)

So the function should be like
as_tree_map<-function(df_3,freq="n"){
  lables= ...
  parents= ...
  N= ...
  data.frame(
    lables=lables,
    parents=parents,
    N=parents
  )
}
df_1_tree_map<-as_tree_map(df_1)
fig <- df_1_tree_map %>% plot_ly(
  type="treemap",
  labels=~labels,
  parents=~parents,
  values=~values,
  marker=list(colorscale='Reds'))

fig

I can not create the function but this is my try
df_1 <- data.frame(  
  cat_1 = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 2),  
  cat_2 = rep(letters[5:6], length=4),  
  N = c(1, 2, 3, 4)  
)  
#labels=c("A", "B" ,"e_A", "f_A", "e_B" ,"f_B")
#parents=c("","","A", "A","B", "B")
#values=c(3,7,1,2,3,4)

df_1_t<-df_1 %>%
  mutate(cat_2=paste(cat_2,cat_1,sep="_")) %>%
  dplyr::rename(parents=cat_1,labels=cat_2) %>%
  dplyr::select(labels,parents,N) %>% data.frame()

df_tree_map<- df_1_t %>%
  group_by(parents) %>%
  summarise(N=sum(N)) %>% 
  dplyr::rename(labels=parents) %>%
  mutate(parents=" ") %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  bind_rows(df_1_t)

> df_tree_map


   labels N parents
1      A 3        
2      B 7        
3    e_A 1       A
4    f_A 2       A
5    e_B 3       B
6    f_B 4       B

fig <- df_tree_map %>% plot_ly(  
  type = "treemap",  
  labels = ~labels,  
  parents = ~parents,  
  values = ~values,  
  marker = list(colorscale = 'Reds')  
)  

fig

the output is:

I remember using a function called as.sunburstDF to create sunburst plots(Here you can find the source of the as.sunburstDF function.). This function is helpful in this case as well:
as.sunburstDF <- function(DF, value_column = NULL, add_root = FALSE, drop_na_nodes = TRUE){
  colNamesDF <- names(DF)
  
  if(is.data.table(DF)){
    DT <- copy(DF)
  } else {
    DT <- data.table(DF, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  }
  
  if(add_root){
    DT[, root := "Total"]  
  }
  
  colNamesDT <- names(DT)
  hierarchy_columns <- setdiff(colNamesDT, value_column)
  numeric_hierarchy_columns <- names(which(unlist(lapply(DT, is.numeric))))
  
  if(is.null(value_column) && add_root){
    setcolorder(DT, c("root", colNamesDF))
  } else if(!is.null(value_column) && !add_root) {
    setnames(DT, value_column, "values", skip_absent=TRUE)
    setcolorder(DT, c(setdiff(colNamesDF, value_column), "values"))
  } else if(!is.null(value_column) && add_root) {
    setnames(DT, value_column, "values", skip_absent=TRUE)
    setcolorder(DT, c("root", setdiff(colNamesDF, value_column), "values"))
  }
  
  for(current_column in setdiff(numeric_hierarchy_columns, c("root", value_column))){
    DT[, (current_column) := apply(.SD, 1, function(x){fifelse(is.na(x), yes = NA_character_, no = toTitleCase(gsub("_"," ", paste(names(x), x, sep = ": ", collapse = " | "))))}), .SDcols = current_column]
  }
  
  hierarchyList <- list()
  for(i in seq_along(hierarchy_columns)){
    current_columns <- colNamesDT[1:i]
    
    if(is.null(value_column)){
      currentDT <- unique(DT[, ..current_columns][, values := .N, by = current_columns], by = current_columns)
    } else {
      currentDT <- DT[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by=current_columns, .SDcols = "values"]
    }
    
    setnames(currentDT, length(current_columns), "labels")
    currentDT[, depth := length(current_columns)-1]
    hierarchyList[[i]] <- currentDT
  }
  
  hierarchyDT <- rbindlist(hierarchyList, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
  
  if(drop_na_nodes){
    hierarchyDT <- na.omit(hierarchyDT, cols = "labels")
    parent_columns <- setdiff(names(hierarchyDT), c("labels", "values", "depth", value_column))
    hierarchyDT[, parents := apply(.SD, 1, function(x){fifelse(all(is.na(x)), yes = NA_character_, no = paste(x[!is.na(x)], sep = ":", collapse = " - "))}), .SDcols = parent_columns]
  } else {
    parent_columns <- setdiff(names(hierarchyDT), c("labels", "values", value_column))
    hierarchyDT[, parents := apply(.SD, 1, function(x){fifelse(x["depth"] == "0", yes = NA_character_, no = paste(x[seq(2, as.integer(x["depth"])+1)], sep = ":", collapse = " - "))}), .SDcols = parent_columns]
  }
  
  hierarchyDT[, ids := apply(.SD, 1, function(x){paste(c(if(is.na(x["parents"])){NULL}else{x["parents"]}, x["labels"]), collapse = " - ")}), .SDcols = c("parents", "labels")]
  hierarchyDT[, union(parent_columns, "depth") := NULL]
  
  return(hierarchyDT)
}

Now, let's use the function:
df_1 <- data.frame(  
  cat_1 = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 2),  
  cat_2 = rep(letters[5:6], length=4),  
  N = c(1, 2, 3, 4)  
)  
#labels=c("A", "B" ,"e_A", "f_A", "e_B" ,"f_B")
#parents=c("","","A", "A","B", "B")
#values=c(3,7,1,2,3,4)
df_tree_map<-as.sunburstDF(df_1,value_column="N") %>%
   mutate(parents=dplyr::if_else(is.na(parents),"",parents)) %>%
  mutate(labels=paste(parents,labels ,sep="")) %>%
  data.frame() 
> df_tree_map 

labels values parents   ids
1      A      3             A
2      B      7             B
3     Ae      1       A A - e
4     Af      2       A A - f
5     Be      3       B B - e
6     Bf      4       B B - f 
fig <- df_tree_map %>% plot_ly(  
  type = "treemap",  
  labels = ~labels,  
  parents = ~parents,  
  values = ~values,  
  marker = list(colorscale = 'Reds')  
)  

fig

However, in the following example, an error occurred:
df_3<-data.frame(
  cat_1=
    rep(LETTERS[1:4],each=4)
  ,
  cat_2=rep(letters[5:6],each=2,len=16),
  cat_3=rep(LETTERS[7:8],len=16)
  ,
  N=rep(1:4,len=16)
  
)
df_tree_map<-as.sunburstDF(df_3,value_column="N") %>%
   mutate(parents=dplyr::if_else(is.na(parents),"",parents)) %>%
  mutate(labels=paste(parents,labels ,sep="")) %>%
  data.frame() 

df_tree_map 
   labels values parents       ids
1       A     10                 A
2       B     10                 B
3       C     10                 C
4       D     10                 D
5      Ae      3       A     A - e
6      Af      7       A     A - f
7      Be      3       B     B - e
8      Bf      7       B     B - f
9      Ce      3       C     C - e
10     Cf      7       C     C - f
11     De      3       D     D - e
12     Df      7       D     D - f
13 A - eG      1   A - e A - e - G
14 A - eH      2   A - e A - e - H
15 A - fG      3   A - f A - f - G
16 A - fH      4   A - f A - f - H
17 B - eG      1   B - e B - e - G
18 B - eH      2   B - e B - e - H
19 B - fG      3   B - f B - f - G
20 B - fH      4   B - f B - f - H
21 C - eG      1   C - e C - e - G
22 C - eH      2   C - e C - e - H
23 C - fG      3   C - f C - f - G
24 C - fH      4   C - f C - f - H
25 D - eG      1   D - e D - e - G
26 D - eH      2   D - e D - e - H
27 D - fG      3   D - f D - f - G
28 D - fH      4   D - f D - f - H

I believe we need to modify this function in some way.
Ultimately, the solution is:
df_tree_map<-as.sunburstDF(df_3,value_column="N") %>%
  mutate(parents=dplyr::if_else(is.na(parents),"",parents)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate( labels=dplyr::if_else(parents == "",labels,
                                paste(parents,labels ,sep=" - "))) %>%
  data.frame() 
df_tree_map 
fig <- df_tree_map %>% plot_ly(  
  type = "treemap",  
  labels = ~labels,  
  parents = ~parents,  
  values = ~values,  
  marker = list(colorscale = 'Reds')  
)  

fig


